# Calculating the x and y coordinate changes since last tick

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics

I'm using PyGame to create automatically moving units.
These units can be given a destination of type tuple with two elements `(x, y)` and the units have a static speed.

I'm calling `units.update(dt)` where `dt` is the time since last update (in milliseconds). I need to calculate how much the unit has moved since last update. Here's my `Unit` class:

```
class Unit(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, speed):
       self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
       self.rect = self.image.get_rect()  # This rect contains x and y for the Unit
       self.speed = speed
       self.destination = None

    def update(self, dt):
        if self.destination is not None and self.speed > 0:
            dist = self.speed * dt
```

This way I can get the hypotenusa (`dist`), but I need the individual directions for `self.rect.x` and `self.rect.y`. How do I get the `dx` and `dy` from `dist`?

Also, here's my `main.py`:

```
import unit
import pygame

pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((960, 720))
units = pygame.sprite.Group()
my_unit = unit.Unit('my_image.png', 3)
units.add(my_unit)
my_unit.destination = (150, 150)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:
    dt = clock.tick(30)
    units.update(dt)
    display.fill((0, 0, 0))
    units.draw(display)
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a variable inside the Unit class that stores the current position as a tuple, just like the direction. I guess it would be initialized at (0,0)?

Every update, calculate the angle from the current position towards the destination. Some basic trigonometry would give you the dx/dy, as as you said you already have the hypotenuse.
I can't help you more on this part because it depends how your unit can move (in diagonal), what the speed represents,...
Don't forget to update the current position afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

You will get a rectangle as big as your image. This rectangle will always start at 0, 0 with a width. and height the same size as the image. So with this information you can calculate on your own what dx and dy are. Unfortunatly there is not a function like `get_rect_x()`.

Comment: Umh... Obviously I will be moving the unit more than once from `(0, 0)`, I just didn't feel like posting a full game here. And I really don't know how to calculate them *for the given `dt`*. Fortunately there is `rect.x` and `rect.y`